# missing separator on Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, autotools

I am now having problems with a autotools generated Makefile, and it first looks like [this](http://cfp.vim-cn.com/cbcDZ). When I was trying `make` an error arised:

```
Makefile:327: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Then, I tried the following change:

```
326,327c326
< LDFLAGS = -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/home/tjm/tmp/fake-root/libgd/usr/local/lib/ -L /home/tjm/tmp/fake-root/libpng/usr/local/lib -L /home/tjm/tmp/fake-root/freetype/usr/local/lib -L /home/tjm/tmp/fake-root/libpng/usr/local/lib -L /home/tjm/tmp/jpeg-6b
<     -static
---
> LDFLAGS = -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/home/tjm/tmp/fake-root/libgd/usr/local/lib/ -L /home/tjm/tmp/fake-root/libpng/usr/local/lib -L /home/tjm/tmp/fake-root/freetype/usr/local/lib -L /home/tjm/tmp/fake-root/libpng/usr/local/lib -L /home/tjm/tmp/jpeg-6b -static
```

But, this time, I got this error:

```
Making all in intl
Makefile:35: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:582: all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:489: all] Error 2
```

The related lines look like these:

```
32   skip_next=no; \
33   strip_trailopt () \
34   { \
35     flg=`printf '%s\n' "$$flg" | sed "s/$$1.*$$//"`; \
36   }; \
```

And I teird a lot of things like:

```
34 { flg=`printf '%s\n' "$$flg" | sed "s/$$1.*$$//"`; }; \

34   { \
35     flg=`printf '%s\n' "$$flg" | sed "s/$$1.*$$//"`; }; \

33   strip_trailopt () { flg=`printf '%s\n' "$$flg" | sed "s/$$1.*$$//"`; }; \
```

and

```
 35 ^Iflg=printf '%s\n' "$$flg" | sed "s/$$1.*$$//"; \$
```

But still got the same error.

Does anyone can give me some ieda about how to fix it?

Comment: If the generated makefile is broken, it probably means makefile.am is broken. Did you write it or is it from another project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: I'm not sure if this is correct in StackOverflow vs SuperUser.)

If you edited the `Makefile`, it'll not be useful as it'll just re-generate out of `Makefile.in`, and that one in turn will be generated out of `Makefile.am`.

Check your `Makefile.am` file, and put `-static` in the same line as everything else; what is happening is that it does not have a continuation symbol at the end of the previous line (`\`), so the variable definition is not continued. And because of that it tries to parse it as a rule, which it's not.